# Update only changed columns with Mysql prepared statements

Tags: mysql

In the following procedure I have simple prepared "update" statement. I have some questions about using this.

1. Main question: **How do I update only the changed columns in a stored procedure?**  It seems like setting update on all columns will overwrite data if another user changes a different column at the right time.  In Zend Framework 2, I typically use TableGateway, which allows me to send in the form array and I think it will only update the columns that I have sent. How do I build a stored procedure to take a variable set to columns to update?
2. With the above in mind, I know I can build a statement with concat and skip the "prepare .. using" bound parameters, but if I do that, then I can't protect against SQL Injection, unless I build my own filtering functions. I'd really prefer to keep the bound parameters. How do I keep those, while still only building a statement that updates only changed columns?  Because I don't see how to change the USING portion to have dynamic input parameters.
3. Also, just a side question. Why is it in Mysql I have to make all those duplicate input parameters? ("set @col1 = v_val1")  Because I can't put v_val1 directly in the USING statement I have to make session variables. I think that really odd we can't put them in directly.
4. Last little question. Should I unset each session variable at the end of the procedure? "set @col1 = null" Wouldn't it be safer to clear those out? I do not use pooled connections now, but I may use this procedure from more than just PHP web server, and other systems may have pooled connections.

I'm probably missing something obvious in this, and/or I'm just asking too much. I do know there will always be some level of timing with user edits. That's not critical, and if it occurs in my current situation, I'll have a log to show users what and who changes things. But I do wonder what I can do at the Mysql procedure level to work around it. Also it seems like Mysql is really lacking in procedure capabilities compared to PostgreSQL or MSSQL, but I am stuck with Mysql for now because of backend system requirements.

Sorry about all the questions. Having hard time finding answers. Thanks so much for you help.

```
create procedure sp_update_mytable (
    in v_id int,
    in v_val1 varchar(10),
    in v_val2 varchar(10),
    in v_val2 varchar(10)
)
begin

    set @id = v_id;
    set @col1 = v_val1;
    set @col2 = v_val2;
    set @col3 = v_val3;

    set @sql = 'UPDATE mytable
                SET
                col1 = ?,
                col2 = ?,
                col3 = ?
                WHERE id = ?';

    prepare stmt from @sql;
    execute stmt using @col1, @col2, @col3, @id;
    deallocate prepare stmt;

end$$
```

Edit: A little background.
It occurs to me I may be trying to solve this problem the wrong way or wrong place. Here's why I am asking. In ZF2 I have TableGateway,and I can send just an array to update and only the columns I want to update. Its super easy and convenient. Example:

```
$result = $this->db->update('mytable', 
            array('col2' => 'my new value 2'),
            array('id' => 2)
);
```

I'd like to make a stored procedure to do this update, but I can't send only the columns I want.  In one system I may want to send col1 and col3, in another, col1 only.  The columns to update are dynamic.

We are building systems that will integrate more than just a web server, which will include some ODBC, some Node.js maybe, possibly others. I wanted to be open to use other systems by building a Stored Procedure to handle certain table updates.

What's occurring to me now is that maybe I can't do this with Stored Procedures. Maybe I need "Middleware" to solve this.  However, the question still stands, is this possible to do in Mysql.  (if not, PostgreSQL?)

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about issuing an `UDPATE` with lots of columns that don't happen to change, don't worry about it.

If you don't have *all* the possible "new values" and want to build a custom `UPDATE` every time, then do just that.

```
$sets = array();
$binds = array();

if (...) {
    $sets[] = "foo = :foo";
    $binds['foo'] = $foo_value;
}
if (...) {
    $sets[] = "bar = :bar";
    $binds['bar'] = $bar_value;
}
...

$sql = "UPDATE ... SET " .
       implode(', ', $sets) .
       " WHERE ...";
$sth = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$sth=>execute($binds);
```

**Stored Procedure**

When using `CONCAT()` to construct a query, be sure to use `QUOTE()` around any values that as suspect -- such as might have quotes in them, or might be subject to 'sql injection'.

See: [String Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_quote) in the MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual.

Comment: Aha! That's some food for thought!  I'll read up and think through the options. Thank you! I suppose if my stored procedure provided some input validation and a quote() , that would work.  Although, it sure seems like unless you are using bound parameters, dynamic SQL is frowned upon. (which I can understand) I'll report back and accept the answer.  Thanks!